# Orthogonality with respect to random eigenvector

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real positive semi-definite random matrix. Let $x$ be the $n\times 1$ normalized eigenvector corresonding to its largest eigenvalue. Suppose I have a real random variable $z$ which is orthogonal to every entry of $A$, i.e.

$$E(za_{ij})=0 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{for all  } 1\leq i,j\leq n $$

Can I show that $z$ is also orthognal to the entries of $x$?

Since $x$ is an eigenvector, there exist some real $\lambda\geq 0$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. If $\lambda\neq 0$ then

$$ x=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j$$

where $a_j$ denotes the $j$th column of $A$. But not sure where to go from here. In fact $\lambda$ is also random here.

EDIT: user1551 suggested an approach that dosen't use the orthogonality assumption(see comments below). But I think we need the assumption of distinct eigenvalues, at least almost surely. If the entries of $A$ are assumed to be continuous random variables, will the eigenvalues be continuously distributed as well?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You need to make assumptions on the independence of all these random quantities to be able to say anything at all.

Comment: @HansEngler Say I assume that $z$ is independent from every entry of $A$. Can I show it in this case?

Comment: If $x$ is an eigenvector, so is $-x$, If $x$ and $-x$ show up equally likely (conditional on $A$ and $z$), isn't $E(zx_i)$ equal to zero?

Comment: @user1551 You mean $E(zx|A,z)=0.5xz-0.5xz=0$ and hence by iterated expectation $E(zx)=0$? Under what conditions will $x$ and $-x$ be equally likely?

Comment: @user1551 Don't we need to assume distinct eigenvalues? Otherwise the normalized eigenvector may not be unique up to sign. Can I assume distinct eigenvalues almost surely?

Comment: How are you assigning a sign to $x$? As noted, if $x$ is an eigenvector, so is $-x$, but for your question to make sense you are presumably only considering one of this pair.

Comment: @Alphie If you assume that $z$ and each $a_{ij}$ are independent, then $0 = E(za_{ij}) = E(z)E(a_{ij})$ implies $E(z) = 0$ and the problem becomes very simple.

Comment: @ComptonScattering Yes only one of the two. But I don’t see how to assign the sign nonrandomly.

Comment: @Alphie there is no standard way to assign a sign to a vector. Without a prescription of how you intend to do this I am afraid your question is underdefined and does not have an answer.

Comment: @ComptonScattering Let $w$ be an independent random variable taking values $\pm 1$ with equal probability. Then I can define the random eigenvector as $wx$ where $x$ is any eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to its largest eigenvalue. Does this work?

Comment: Yes, but the expectation values you want to calculate are trivially all zero. So I guess this is not what you meant?

Comment: @ComptonScattering This is good for me. Can you show the calculations for the zero expectation? If $A$ has repeated eigenvalues then $x$ may not be unique up to sign, and the distribution of $wx$ is not well-defined. Is this a zero probability event if the entries of $A$ are continuously distributed?